# Moving folders using c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a program to move folders to a new location.  That's easy enough using `Directory.move()`.

The problem I'm having is that I only want to move folder names that are read in from a text file.  I have it to the point where I can move the folders, I've read in the folder names into an array.

I just can't seem to come up with the logic for checking the names from that array then moving them.  How could this be done?

I have this code:

```
string sourceDirectory = @"C:\Users\Steve\Documents\old folder";
string destinationDirectory = @"C:\Users\Steve\Documents\new folder";
try 
{
    string[] file = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Steve\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FileCopier\FileCopier\File.txt"); 
    foreach(string folder in file) 
    { 
        Directory.Move(sourceDirectory, destinationDirectory); 
    }
}
```

It doesn't seem to be picking just the names in the text file and moving only them.

Comment: Take a folder name from the array, do whatever *checking the names* means, and then move the directory if it's appropriate to do so. Repeat with the next folder name from the array until you've done them all. What specific problem are you having? Please post the code that shows your efforts, explain the *specific problem* you've encountered, and ask a more realistic question than *How can this be done?*.

Comment: What do you mean by *"checking the names"*? How are you defining the destination directory? Are you trying to preserve some part of the original path? Some sample input and expected output would be very useful, along with the relevant code you have so far.

Comment: Hi @CSharpDude. I see you are new to StackOverflow. Please take a minute to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to learn how to properly ask questions in the future. Also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers to learn what to do when someone answers your question.

Comment: That's seems to work Alexander! The only thing is that it seems to skip any folders that have spaces (i.e: new folder) . Is there a way I can catch those also?

Answer (score -1):

You are read the values into an array and performing a loop with them but you are using the values when you call  `Directory.Move`

You need to combined the directory names with those in your array.

When working with files and folders the best way to combine strings is using `System.IO.Path.Combine`

Using your problem code:

```
string sourceDirectory = @"C:\Users\Steve\Documents\old folder";
string destinationDirectory = @"C:\Users\Steve\Documents\new folder"; 
try 
{ 
    string[] file = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Steve\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FileCopier\FileCopier\File.txt"); 
    foreach(string folder in file) { 
         Directory.Move(Path.Combine(sourceDirectory, folder), Path.Combine(destinationDirectory, folder)); } 
    }
}
catch (Exception ex) {Console.WriteLine(Ex.ToString()); }
```

Comment: After stepping away from it and thinking it out some more I thought I could accomplish this with a foreach loop. It seems to iterate through now but it's not selecting the names in my text file. Here's what I got so far..

Comment: string sourceDirectory = @"C:\Users\Steve\Documents\old folder";
string destinationDirectory = @"C:\Users\Steve\Documents\new folder";

            try
            {
                string[] file = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Steve\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FileCopier\FileCopier\File.txt");
                
                foreach(string folder in file)
                {
                    Directory.Move(sourceDirectory, destinationDirectory);
                }

Comment: Hmm, how can I keep my formatting when posting here?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be picking just the names in the text file and moving only them.

Comment: did you use the code I posted? You code is moving only your sourceDirectoy and Destination directory? You are not passing the `folder` variable to `Directory.Move`

Comment: How about not answering until the poster edits the question, so that it has some value to future readers that isn't buried in this private discussion the two of you are having in comments?

Comment: @KenWhite you are right. I have edited the question to make it more valuable to future readers.

Comment: What would have been proper is not to have answered the question until the poster did so. It encourages them to learn more suitable habits in the future. Answering bad questions rewards the lack of effort to provide the details in the question and encourages the poster to do so again in the future because they know they'll get help anyway.